# Resharper - Unit Test Runner - Hide Namespace

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper, resharper-plugins

Is there a way to hide the Namespace in Resharper Unit Test Runner?  I'm using the Project Structure Group By and the Namespace is just cluttering the Window:

[image: Namespaces Cluttering Unit Test Session Window]

Could this be fixed quickly in an extensions?

Otherwise, I created a YouTrack issue with JetBrains.  If you agree, please vote: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-414772

UPDATE:
I'm using Resharper 8.2 (Build 8.2.0.2160).  If I recall correctly, I've had this issue on 7 as well.

I am writing NUnit Tests

Comment: I am using Resharper 8.2 and it doesn't seem to have this issue. Which version are you using?

Comment: Excellent question, let me update the question ...

Comment: @VladimirSachek if you are also using Reshaper 8.2, what does your Test Runner look like if Group By Project Structure?  Does it not display a classes Full Name (ie including namespace?)

Comment: Sorry I was a bit confused. You are right in Projects grouping it displays full namespace paths for classes. I believe this is by intent to let you distinguish classes with the same names. But I agree that in your case it cluttering window quite much